# Snowflake GIS - outline of merged polygons

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gis, geospatial

I realised that many functions in Snowflake do not work on `GeometryCollection`, hence I'm trying to merge polygons into one.

I have a table with Spanish municipalities and I want to join some of them. When I use `ST_COLLECT`, it works well by joining them together but the output, obviously, is a collection.

I would like to also have it as one polygon but I can't find a way to do it:

```sql
-- geo_shape is a result of TO_GEOGRAPHY() on a GeoJSON column
SELECT
  ST_BUFFER(ST_COLLECT(geo_shape), 0)
FROM municipalities
```

gives me `Invalid argument types for function 'ST_BUFFER': (GEOGRAPHY, NUMBER(1,0))` error because the first argument has to be `Geometry` not `Geography`

If I change to `ST_UNION` then I get `Invalid argument types for function 'ST_UNION': (GEOGRAPHY)`.

I feel like I'm either missing a piece of knowledge, or I need to do some converting but essentially I'm looking for a Merge function equivalent from ArcGIS.